# How can I transform a char array to a string representing its value in hexadecimal?

Tags: c, char, hex

I am trying to convert an array of chars into an array of hexadecimal numbers.
Each char in the input array will be converted to two chars that represent the corresponding hexadecimal number.

This is my input:

```
char input[3] = "over";
```

This would be the output:

```
char output[6] = "6f766572";
```

How can I achieve this conversion in C without libraries? Thanks in advance.

My code is currently as follows:

```c
void convert(char *input, int inputsize) {
  char c;
  char output[inputsize * 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < inputsize; i++) {
    c = input[i]
    // change c to hex here
    // put each letter of the hex into output[i * 2] and output[i * 2 + 1]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing it? How far did you get?

Comment: Where did you get those array sizes from? Also, null termination.

Comment: Beware: `"6f766572"`  takes 9 chars, 8 for the characters and 1 for the string terminator.

Comment: Please confirm your _actual_ question is: _How  can I transform a char to a string representing it's value in hexadécimal( e.g. 65 -> "41")?_

Comment: *"How can I achieve this conversion in C without external libraries?"* - not even the standard C library?

Comment: @user253751 I have achieved this with libraries (sprint, strtol) but am having trouble with not using libraries... Sorry about that

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the title.

Comment: Every non-floating point, intrinsic  type can be easily expressed as a hexadecimal value.  The way a value is dressed up in its formatting does not change its value, or the way it is stored.  Just change your formatting, i.e. use `"%x"`, or `"0x%x"` if you want to see the `0x`.

Comment: @mmmdwldmm closely read by comment again

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes I confirm it. 'A' -> 65 -> "41"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't wanna use library functions, you'll have to build a simple lookup table yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h> // only for printing the result

const char table[] = "0123456789abcdef";

int main(void) {
    char src[5 + 1] = "hello";
    char dst[5 * 2 + 1];
    char *s, *d;

    for (s = src, d = dst; *s != '\0'; s++, d += 2) {
        const unsigned char lo = *s & 0xf;
        const unsigned char hi = *s >> 4;

        *d = table[hi];
        *(d + 1) = table[lo];
    }

    *d = '\0';

    puts(dst);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the free fish. I'll come back tomorrow for more, make sure to have it ready. Salmon fillet is acceptable.

Comment: No C libraries?  (you even pointed this out under another answer: _OP specifically asked for a solution without using any_)

Comment: @Lundin it's pretty clear that OP already knows the basic concept, as they already explain that in the comments of their answer. Maybe all they need to know is how to extract the two nibbles from a byte? Just showing the code is both easier and faster for such an easy problem.

Comment: The original code didn't contain any attempt by the OP, that was just added through an edit.

Comment: @ryyker well, I'm not going to print the string by myself through raw asm syscalls, if that's what you mean. The only header I add is for printing the result. The actual computation is not done using library functions. I can surely also print that out without libraries if you want me to...

Comment: @Lundin well, yeah... which prompted me to answer this.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate anyhow, but I can't be bothered to find one...

Comment: @Lundin I searched for one but could only find answers with the classical `sprintf` approach.

Answer (score 4):

- Create a loop running until it finds `\0` in the input buffer.
- For each character number `[i]` in the input string, mask out the upper and lower nibble of that byte. Make sure to use unsigned types.
- Run each of the two nibbles through a lookup table such as `const char HEX_LOOKUP [16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";`, where the value of the nibble is used as index.
- Store the result in output index `[i*2]` and `[i*2+1]`, since the output will be exactly twice as large as the input.
- Null terminate the output string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
void toHex(const char *in, int len, char *out)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        sprintf(&out[i * 2], "%x", in[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char input[] = "over";
    char output[32];
    memset(output, 0, sizeof(output));
    toHex(input, sizeof(input), output);
    puts(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that `sprintf` and `memset` are library functions, and OP specifically asked for a solution without using any.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli: The OP asked for a solution without *external* libraries but is the libc an external library? If you think it is, how would you write a program without linking it to libc? Well, you could invoke the link editor directly and just link against `crtn.o` but that doesn't count imho. In my eyes, the answer is correct. If you ignore the misplaced curlies. ;)

Comment: @GuidoFlohr granted, the wording is bad, but [that's what they meant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938780/how-can-i-transform-a-char-array-to-a-string-representing-its-value-in-hexadecim/63938967#comment113064226_63938780).